# Проверка длины поля ввода с маской jquery

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, asp.net-mvc

Пишу на asp.net mvc. Через атрибут

```
[StringLength (, MinimumLength=,ErrorMessage="")]
```

Получается тоже самое что и с jq

Есть маска

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.inputmask/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#phone').inputmask("+7(999)999-9999");       
});
</script>
```

Поле ввода

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phoneord, new { @class = "form-control", id = "phone" })
```

Как проверять количество цифр в поле без учета маски, пробую убирать символы "_" через jq, но все равно такая строка "+7( )___-____" воспринимается как 15 символов. А мне нужно чтобы учитывались только числа на месте "_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот 7 цифр

```js
$(".phone").mask("+7(999)999-9999");
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
 
  <input type="text" class="phone">
```

вот 6 цифр

```js
$(".phone").mask("+7(999)999-999");
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
 
  <input type="text" class="phone">
```

вот 5 цифр

```js
$(".phone").mask("+7(999)99999");
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
 
  <input type="text" class="phone">
```

вот ещё 5 цифр

```js
$(".phone").mask("+7(999)99-999");
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
 
  <input type="text" class="phone">
```

маска проверяет количество , или может что не понял я ??? 
при 7 ом номере 15 знаков 
при 6 ти 14 знаков 
при 5 ти значном номере 13 знаков и тд 
если нужна какая то другая проверка  - по идее регулярным выражением тогда проверять

Comment: Да, помогло регулярное выражение[RegularExpression(@"^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$", ErrorMessage = "Проверьте номер.")]